# How should the word "dashboard", in software or web applications, be translated?

Tags: tradução

In software (particularly web applications), there is a concept of a dashboard, which is a screen or view where I can review high-level summaries or high-priority alerts, and take appropriate action, all from one place.

When translating the software into Portuguese, what is the best word to use for "dashboard"?  Online dictionaries suggest "painel de instrumentos," but that sounds like something in an airplane cockpit, not a software screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do say *painel*, at least here in Brazil. it may be just painel, or something more specific like *painel de controle* or *painel administrativo*. *Painel de instruments* sounds like something physical, like a plane's dashboard as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In a business context, you can use **INDICADORES**

Comment: Não entendo porque -1, e nem comentar o motivo.